# Python SymPy - StrictlyLessThan to Integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, sympy

I would like to multiply a `StrictlyLessThan` with a float but in order to do that, I need to transform `flag` into an integer or float. How do I do that?

```
import sympy.numpy as snp

def function(x):
    square_sum = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2
    flag = square_sum < 10
    cubic_sum = x[0]**3 + x[1]**3
    return flag * cubic_sum

function(snp.array([2, 3]))  # Raises an error
```

## Alternative

Notice that I would equally be happy with something like this, but this returns the error `TypeError: cannot determine truth value of Relational`

```
def function(x):
    square_sum = x[0]**2 + x[1]**2
    if square_sum < 10:
        return x[0]**3 + x[1]**3
    else:
        return 0.0
```

Comment: Why?  `flag` is a relational. It doesn't make sense to multiply it, not even it can be evaluated to True/False,

Comment: @hpaulj Perhaps in sympy it doesn't have sense, but in normal python I'd simply cast it as integer. The idea is that I want to obtain `0.0` if flag is `False` and obtain the `cubic_sum` if `flag` is `True`

Comment: @hpaulj Added some more detail to the question

Comment: Perhaps I could use piecewise..

Comment: That relational error is like the ambiguity error you get if you use a numpy array in an `if`.  `if` expects a simple true/false, not many from an array, or a sympy relation that depends on a symbol.

Comment: I think Piecewise is what you need. Btw what is sympy.numpy?

Comment: Yes, a numpy boolean array can be treated as as 0/1 int array in multiplication.  But a `sympy.Relational` cannot. https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.relational